# Google showing H1 text instead of page TITLE in search result?

Tags: google, title, search

I always thought Google shows page title (whatever is in the `<title>` tag of the page) as 1st line of each result.

But looking at the [search "orologi da collezione"](http://www.google.it/#hl=it&biw=1920&bih=834&q=orologi+da+collezione&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=61d7c31a66760ab2) below, it seems Google is showing as 1st line of content the `<H1>` tag.

[image]

Am I right? **Is Google showing the content of the H1 tag as 1st line of the serach result** or something else got from meta description?

Even more and more interesting when [searching for "vendita orologi"](http://www.google.it/#hl=it&biw=1920&bih=834&q=vendita+orologi&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=61d7c31a66760ab2) the same site comes out, but this time it shows the real page title as 1st line:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Page title
>
> [image: Page title]
>
> If we’ve detected that a particular result has one of the above issues with its title, we may try to generate an improved title from anchors, on-page text, or other sources. However, sometimes even pages with well-formulated, concise, descriptive titles will end up with different titles in our search results to better indicate their relevance to the query. There’s a simple reason for this: the title tag as specified by a webmaster is limited to being static, fixed regardless of the query. Once we know the user’s query, we can often find alternative text from a page that better explains why that result is relevant. Using this alternative text as a title helps the user, and it also can help your site. Users are scanning for their query terms or other signs of relevance in the results, and a title that is tailored for the query can increase the chances that they will click through.
>
> If you’re seeing your pages appear in the search results with modified titles, check whether your titles have one of the problems described above. If not, consider whether the alternate title is a better fit for the query.

Read the rest here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624

Comment: +1 for the quote and link. But I don't see how to disable the H1 thing as you suggest.

Comment: i think this will be more relevant

Comment: @Sevki: Unfortunately, the link is broken. Can you update it or tell us which question it was referring to?