# Strange title appearing in Google search results for a video

Tags: google-search, search-results

Google is displaying a strange result for my video site: I do not have any idea where it got my video's duration and why it's displayed in this way - take a look at the screenshot below:

[image]

I don't have the duration in the title tags in my site, and also the meta description on my site is clean...what's causing this?

Also I don't have a video sitemap submitted to Google, I made a simple sitemap with URL only.

Comment: Can you clarify if your meta description tag is empty, and what you meant in the last sentence?

Comment: I mean clean not clear sorry, this means that i dont have duration of videos in meta tags...

Answer (score 1):

Since 2012, Google may change the result titles.

See [my answer to a similar question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/44374/17633) for links to Google’s documentation about it.

Google uses several ways how to find information for result titles. As I quoted in my linked answer, Google has algorithms that take *a)* content of the page and *b)* references to this page into account.

So Google may have parsed the video length out of your page (resp. the video itself), or found a reference to it somewhere else.

Comment: Yes i know this, but cant understand from where google get this result about duration... im use self hosted videos and jwplayer on site...

Comment: @MilanMilosevic: As I quoted in my linked answer, Google uses several ways how to find information for result titles: "[…] we have **algorithms** that generate alternative titles […]"; "[…] completely automated and takes into account both **the content of a page** as well as **references to it** that appear on the web […]". So Google may have parsed the video length out of your page, or found a reference to it somewhere else.