# My title tag doesn't appear to be getting crawled by Google properly

Tags: seo, search-results, title

My title is:

```
<title>School Management Software, College & University Management Software, Cloud ERP Software</title>
```

However it's showing up like this in Google:
[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Any insight would be really helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Bare with me. I will explain what changes Google has made followed by how Google decides how to make the SERP link and what specifically happened in your case.

Google has been changing the look and feel of the SERPs since March 2014 with the hopes of improving the user experience and click-through rates (CTR). It is believed that changing the SERP look and feel along with the various options Google decided to implement improves search results and benefits the sites that appear in the SERPs. Google has made several changes, but has settled on the ones that appear to be most effective.

Part of the changes include changing the font size of the SERP link. Prior to the change, the SERP link would have be taken directly from the page `title` tag with a character limit of 55 characters. This would mean that any title greater than 55 characters in length could have an ellipsis (...) added to the end to indicate that the title was truncated. For a period the ellipsis was dropped and then returned.

Now the title length limit is measured in 512 pixels and not characters. Letters that are wider such as G, K, and W significantly reduce the number of characters that appear in the SERP link. Today, the SERP link can be 45 to 50 characters generally, and possibly as long as 55 characters.

When Google sees a long `title` tag it may choose to use:

- What appears to be a brand name which can be the domain name with or
  without the TLD. (most likely)
- What it knows to be a brand name. (fairly likely)
- The first header `h1` tag. (very likely)
- A portion of the content that closely matches the search query.
  (fairly likely)
- Information from a publicly available source such as ODP DMOZ (not
  likely).
- Information from rich snippets mark-up. (less likely)
- Text from anchors text. (less likely)

Also note that these options apply if the `title` tag is missing or empty. As well, if a `title` tag is short, Google will likely chose to brand your SERP link with your domain name with TLD.

*In your case, it appears that because your `title` tag is longer than the prescribed limit (89 characters), Google decided to take the first option in the list using your domain name as a brand name without the TLD.*

To avoid this, manage your `title` tag length and use the `Google Webmaster Tools -> Fetch as Google` tool to test how a change would appear in the SERPs.

Comment: @SatyaPalNegi I update the answer hoping to be of good service. Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify or expand.

Comment: It's interesting to note that the OP's title is displayed (truncated) once you select _Search Tools_ and change _All Results_ to _Verbatim_. So it's possible that they do view the name of the company as a brand (it's not in their `h1` however).

Comment: @dan I will have to look for it again sometime where Google talks about branding and determining brands. They are bullish on the notion that domain names are brands and do want to take full advantage potential future brands by recognizing them early. While sometimes I think Google goes too far down the rabbit hole, I actually think they got this concept right. After all, isn't it our goal to create brand recognition for our websites? Where it fails however, is not all sites deserve brand recognition. It should remain something that we strive for and do the work for before being rewarded.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the search query, Google may decide to display a different title. If your meta title was only recently updated, you might have to wait until Google decides to change it. Have a read of [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en):

> If we've detected that a particular result has one of the above issues
>   with its title, we may try to generate an improved title from anchors,
>   on-page text, or other sources. However, sometimes even pages with
>   well-formulated, concise, descriptive titles will end up with
>   different titles in our search results to better indicate their
>   relevance to the query. There’s a simple reason for this: the title
>   tag as specified by a webmaster is limited to being static, fixed
>   regardless of the query. Once we know the user’s query, we can often
>   find alternative text from a page that better explains why that result
>   is relevant. Using this alternative text as a title helps the user,
>   and it also can help your site. Users are scanning for their query
>   terms or other signs of relevance in the results, and a title that is
>   tailored for the query can increase the chances that they will click
>   through.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Perhaps GoogleBot and index needed time to catch up.

[image: skyknect google search result]

Comment: In the U.S. (using `google.com`), I'm seeing what the OP has in their screenshot (currently as the third link from the top). Are you possibly using Google Search in another locale? Maybe the OP has different versions of the site based on language or country.

Comment: @dan Excellent point! Not all of the various Google sites are configured exactly the same. The SERP redesign was in the U.S. on the .com site. I cannot tell you where else any of it may have showed up.