# Why is my domain name getting appended to the title in Google SERP?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, search-results, title

Suppose my site is `example.com`.

Now all the results for my site are displayed like this in Google search:

> How to make cookies - example.com

However, my title is only `How to make cookies`, and `example.com` is not in the title.

This is a custom site, and not a Blogger or WordPress site. I know this happens with Blogger and WordPress blogs since they contain the domain name in their title by default.

Comment: Your title tags are too short. Google is branding your SERP links. You can avoid this by making title tags 45-55 characters in length (actually about 512 pixels). Branding the SERP link is not a bad thing however. On one site I intentionally brand all my titles. Cheers!!

Comment: This answer has three links in it that should help you to understand what is going on. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/79086/what-would-cause-incorect-titles-to-be-listed-in-google/79087#79087 Today, the title tag can be longer. You can use Fetch as Google in Google Search Console to play around with different titles/title lengths to tune a perfect title for your SERP link.

Comment: @closetnoc i think it is wrong because my title is 64 characters still google adding my Domain to it. I am not sure why. Domain is appearing complete but my page title is shrinked with ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alter your title tag to complete their character limit. If not google will take your website URL or your H1 tag as your extra tag. Title is for user to understand what is your page is all about so that elaborate your title for user understanding. Google things that 60 would be the best limit to understand what your page is all about.
   Most of them uses some of the highly searched related keywords for mention theri titles that was also one of the good way to increase the visibility of your website. Utilise all the charecter limit for title and don't exceed that and don't use less character to write title.

Comment: My title is 64 characters. 65 characters fits well in google search but still google is  adding my domain along with it. Domain is appearing complete but my page title is shrinked with ....

Comment: Character limit is not an issue definitely. My Page title Appears like - "Title-65-char...... - GPO Retro"  Title is 65 char but its shrinked with dots to have title place there