# Ideal title size for Google Search

Tags: seo, google-search, title

Is it true that Google Search can’t read more than 70 characters of a webpage title?

Comment: They can read it just fine. But at some point they stop caring.

Comment: This answer should help some: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65767/title-in-google-does-not-match-title-of-document/65768#65768 along with this one: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69050/my-title-tag-doesnt-appear-to-be-getting-crawled-by-google-properly/69080#69080

Comment: I'd stick with under 66 characters. Anything more will cause excess text to be cut off and replaced with three dots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the google SEO guidelines (Google Search Engine Optimization
Starter Guide - Page 4):

> Use brief, but descriptive titles Titles can be both short and
>   informative. If the title is too long, Google will show only a portion
>   of it in  the search result.

AVOID:

- using extremely lengthy titles that are unhelpful to users
- stuffing unneeded keywords in your title tags

[Link to: Google Search Engine Optimization
Starter Guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.de/de/de/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf)

As outlined, titles should not be too long - eventually make use of the "description" meta tag 
(Google Search Engine Optimization
Starter Guide - Page 6)

> Description  meta  tags  are  important  because  Google  might  use 
>   them as snippets for your pages.

To answer the question: to me this is obvious - titles should be as short as possible - for a detailed description the description meta tag should be applied. For your specific question - there is no direct answer - as im aware <55 chars is perfect, ~65 chars are reasonable but still a lot, 75 absolute maximum and should be avoided.