# I have product comparasion long title

Tags: seo, google-search-console, facebook, title, comparison

I have Website with product comparasion.
Also I am thinking what to do with my titles.

```
4 product comparasion:
Apple iPhone 6S Plus vs Samsung galaxy S7 Edge vs Microsoft Lumia 820 XL DTE SIM DUAL vs Xiaomi Redmi 1S – Compare – Example.com
2 product comparasion:
Apple iPhone 6S Plus vs Samsung galaxy S7 Edge – Compare – Example.com (Facebook displays 110 characters while sharing on Fan page)
3 product comparasion:
Apple iPhone 6S Plus vs Samsung galaxy S7 Edge vs Microsoft Lumia 820 XL DTE SIM DUAL – Compare – Example.com
```

These are long titles, Facebook wraps it araound 110. Search engines display up to 70~75 and add "..." dots.

Any ideas for these long titles? Informations what to do? (titles goes up to 150~170)

If I cut the title characters, should I add on my page  and put full in the description (~160 characters)?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been hashed around so many times. Here are three answers I have written that should help - each is a bit different: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/title-tag-different-from-title-appearing-in-google/69206#69206 
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69050/my-title-tag-doesnt-appear-to-be-getting-crawled-by-google-properly/69080#69080 
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65767/title-in-google-does-not-match-title-of-document/65768#65768

Comment: Anytime!! We are here for you. We have some real experts here! Though it can be a bit quiet on the weekends. ;-) See? Webmaster do have lives.