# Fixing website title on Bing

Tags: web-crawlers, title, bing-webmaster-tools, search-results

I have recently created my own portfolio website, and the title meta tags specify the title of my front page as: "Thomas Russell's Portfolio and Blog", but when I search for "Thomas Russell's Portfolio" on Bing, I get the following:

[image]

I'm not sure why it has decided that "My social networks" is the title for the page, as it isn't (and has never been) the `<title>` meta tag, or even an `<h1>` tag, so it can't be that this is a cache'd result.

Does anyone have any advice for how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Bing may change titles in their SERPs (Just [like Google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/44374/17633)).

See Bing’s blog post [How Does Bing Choose The Title For My Web Page?](http://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2014/06/23/how-does-bing-choose-the-title-for-my-web-page/):

> Sometimes, despite a webmaster’s best efforts, Bing may choose to serve a title that is different to the title of a web site or document.

Why "My social networks"? Maybe because it is your *first* heading on the homepage, which is probably not the best choice. Your site name (resp. your personal name) should ideally be the first heading in the document (as a `h1`).

Comment: I often recommend that the one and only h1 tag be similar but not identical to the title tag. This is a good case for that argument. However, it is not an absolute rule.

Comment: you didn't tell how to recover my old title