# Google is adding "Archive" to the title of tag and category pages and not using the meta description

Tags: web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I am wondering why Google is indexing my tags and categories as archives. Is that OK to be like that or I should change them?

How to change them? Actually it looks so awkward!

I have configured my categories with descriptions and everything but still Google is not showing in a proper way.

Below I am attaching the reference images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The title tag is too short. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83093/even-though-i-have-title-tag-google-show-the-name-of-the-link-instead-of-the/83097#83097

Comment: As for the description meta tag, that is highly dependent upon the search query. It is not a given that it will show up the way you want each and every time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should I Increase the tag length? Actually I have website categories also in short like Technology, Tech, How To? etc. Should I make them also bit longer?