# Google cuts my page title on search results

Tags: seo, google, title, search-results

It seems that Google cuts my page title on search results. Is there a best practice to provide titles?

The page `www.currenttime.tv/content/article/27236953.html` should have this title: *Кто такой 'бог Кузя'? Все что вы хотели знать о задержанном лидере секты*.

And here's the title on Google:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what's wrong with the title you're seeing? What's missing?

Comment: Problem is that the original page title is "Кто такой &quot;бог Кузя&quot;? Все что вы хотели знать о задержанном лидере секты " and google just type a strange piece of that

Comment: It's a touch long. Try something simpler like `Кто такой "бог Кузя"? Все что вы хотели знать` perhaps. It's more likely search engines will reference that, and it's more eye-catching to searchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [moz.com](https://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag)

> Google typically displays the first 50-60 characters of a title tag,
>   or as many characters as will fit into a 512-pixel display. If you
>   keep your titles under 55 characters, you can expect at least 95% of
>   your titles to display properly. Keep in mind that search engines may
>   choose to display a different title than what you provide in your
>   HTML. Titles in search results may be rewritten to match your brand,
>   the user query, or other considerations.

Google may show the H1 tag of that page instead of title tag based on the relevancy of the page.

[Google showing H1 text instead of page TITLE in search result?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/google-showing-h1-text-instead-of-page-title-in-search-result)

Comment: Thank you but  - there is just about 10 characters used and the only H1 contains the same text as title - the long one

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't force Google to display your entire title tag. You provide a title and Google estimates if it's relevant to the page and if it considers that is not, it can decide to change it (cutting it, rewriting it, etc.).

If you want to be sure to see your entire title tag on Google, just do what's necessary to use a relevant title for your page.

Comment: What is the most relevant title for a newspaper article than the origin title ?